# Event on input within div acting differently to event on input within a label

Tags: html, jquery

This is an odd one but I'm sure there's a simple explanation. Can someone explain to me why an event on an input within a div acts differently to an event on input within a label. Please see the following fiddle as an example:

https://jsfiddle.net/anthill/h8v106o7

```js
$('#container .switch input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(e) {
  alert($(this).data('message'));
})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 10px;
}
h5 {
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
.switch {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0;
  height: 34px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}
.switch:after, .switch:before {
  background-color: #9bca3e;
  color: #fff;
  content: "On";
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  padding: 7px 0;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  width: 51%;
  /* This is so the darker color doesn't show through the rounded corners of the knob */
}
.switch:before {
  background-color: #999;
  content: "Off";
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
}
.switch .knob {
  background: #f7f7f7;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
  height: 100%;
  left: -1px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  width: 40px;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.15s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.15s ease;
  transition: all 0.15s ease;
}
.switch .knob:before, .switch .knob:after {
  border: 4px solid transparent;
  border-left-color: inherit;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: 2px;
  margin-top: -3px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 0;
}
.switch .knob:before {
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: inherit;
  margin-left: -10px;
}
.switch input {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.switch input:checked + .knob {
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" checked data-message="Checkbox 1"/>
    <span class="knob"></span>
  </label>
  <div class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" checked data-message="Checkbox 2" />
    <span class="knob"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

The change event fires fine on the first checkbox but not at all on the second. Is it something to do with the label sharing the event on the hidden input, whereas the div does not do this?

Comment: _"The change event fires fine on the first checkbox but not at all on the second."_ They both fire for me. Oh now I see. You left out the CSS in your fiddle. Update your question here with it please. We need a [mcve]

Comment: sorry you need to click on the fiddle not the code snippet as I forgot to apply the css

Comment: I suspect something else is bubbling up or interfering with the Click event that would trigger the Change event.

Answer (score 1):

Testing here: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/947vsjpa/5/

You can see that Click events are happening on the Switch & Knob, yet not on the Input. The `label` element has a relationship with `input`. The click event upon the Label can effect the state of the Input. `div` does not have this relationship; therefore, the click event does not reach the invisible element.

How do you want to fix this? Use Label element for both? Capture the click event on the `.switch` and then trigger a click of the Input.

Consider the following: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/947vsjpa/18/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $('#container .switch').click(function(event) {
    console.log(event.type, event.target);
    event.preventDefault();
    var $input = $("input[type='checkbox']", this)
    $input.prop("checked", !$input.prop("checked"));
    alert($input.data("message"));
  });
});
```

This changes the property even if it's not visible and can't be clicked upon.